# Identify SKU id's that have changed status twice in a historical table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a historical table which has id, date and status columns. I am trying to identify all the instances where the id's have changed from status 1(Active) to 0(Inactive) and came back to 1(Active again). I want to create a pivot table with all the distinct id's as rows, and all the dates as column values. Since, this is a historical table and there are around 10M distinct id's, I am trying to see what would be an ideal/efficient way to pull the data.

The data looks like this:

```
id       date       status
I01234   5/12/2023  1
I14690   4/13/2021  0
```

The final structure of the data:

```
id      01/01/2021 01/02/2021 01/03/2021 ........ 10/31/2023
I01234  1          1          1                   0
I14690  1          0          0                   1
```

Comment: The base table has data from 2015 till 2023 where each date has around 400K distinct id's and the total number of records are around 15B for these 8 years and the total number of distinct id's are around 10.2M

Comment: Okay, will update the question accordingly

Comment: Is this two questions or is that latter part with the pivot how you were figuring to approach the solution? Meaning, are you just trying to get the id's and dates which go active->inactive->active and the pivot was a means to that end? Or are you really dead set on the pivot?

Comment: The latter part with the pivot is the approach I am trying and I am not dead set on the pivot and I am open to any other solution as well.

Comment: is there more statuses than 1 and 0?

Comment: Yes, there are around 10 distinct status, out of which we need only 1 and 0

Comment: Let's say a status goes 1 => 0 => 5 => 1, is that a valid chain of events you're looking for? And also, are you looking for just one such chain, or do you want all of them

Comment: Yes, that is a valid chain, as long as it moved from 1 to 0 and then 1 again, this is the only chain I am looking for

Comment: `I want to create a pivot table with all the distinct id's as rows, and all the dates as column values`.    Shame!

Comment: What about `1 -> 4 -> 0 -> 5 -> 0 -> 1`?  Also, you say 'instances', does that mean `1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1` would show up twice?     What about `1 -> 0 -> 5 -> 0 -> 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the all the records for each id which have moved from active->inactive->active. Note that this will pick up a record that has this lifecycle at any point, regardless of it's current status.

Also assumes that the pivot is not necessary and we only want the ids/records.

There are two main conditions in the inactive_sandwich clause.

The first checks to see (via EXISTS) if there are any records with active status for that id earlier than a inactive.

Second is the same idea, but checks for active records later than the load date of the inactive.

If both of these are true that means you have an earlier "active", a "inactive", and a later "active".

This result will only give you the inactive records, so the last clause picks up all records which are associated with those ids.

```
create table some_test_data 
  ( id varchar(100),
    status integer,
    load_date date
  )

insert into some_test_data values ('abc',1,cast('2023-01-01' as datetime));
insert into some_test_data values ('abc',0,cast('2023-01-02' as datetime));
insert into some_test_data values ('abc',1,cast('2023-01-03' as datetime));
insert into some_test_data values ('cde',1,cast('2023-01-04' as datetime));
insert into some_test_data values ('cde',1,cast('2023-01-05' as datetime));
insert into some_test_data values ('efg',1,cast('2023-01-05' as datetime));
insert into some_test_data values ('efg',0,cast('2023-01-05' as datetime));

with inactive_sandwich as (
    select *
      from some_test_data t1
     where t1.status = 0
       and exists
             ( select 1
                 from some_test_data earlier_active
                where t1.id = earlier_active.id
                  and t1.load_date > earlier_active.load_date
                  and earlier_active.status = 1                
             )
       and exists
             ( select 1
                 from some_test_data later_active
                where t1.id = later_active.id
                  and t1.load_date < later_active.load_date
                  and later_active.status = 1                
             )
)
select * 
  from some_test_data t1 
 where exists
         (
           select 1
             from inactive_sandwich t2
            where t1.id = t2.id

         )
```

Comment: True. Added some language.

Comment: Thank you, this is working, however it takes around 30 mins for my historical data of around 15B records